# LNK2019 error One DLL linking wih MFC DLL

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, linker

I'm new to MFC.

I'm trying to make a DLL in MFC, which links to another DLL.

The problem is when I try and compile, I get a LNK2019 error thrown at me for a function present in the DLL which I'm trying to link.

LNK2019 is when the DLL or the function inside the DLL is not being found.

I've taken all steps, the DLL is placed in a known location, the lib is placed in a known location too, it's been added in the additional dependencies, all correct switches have been applied ( ones I know of anyway ).

I've used Dependency walker and I know the DLL, to which I'm trying to link, exposes this function.
I've other examples of use of the function, and I'm trying to use it exactly like it.
The .lib and .dll are in agreement, i.e., they're consistent with each other.

But still the error persists.

***EDIT***
This is the error message :

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall
>   PwServer::Connect(wchar_t const *,unsigned long,unsigned long *)"
>   (_*imp*?Connect@PwServer@@QAE_NPB_WKPAK@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: bool __thiscall CPwServer::Connect(class
>   ATL::CStringT > >,unsigned long,unsigned long *)"
>   (?Connect@CPwServer@@QAE_NV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@KPAK@Z)

And this is the call I use to access the DLL.

```
bool conn = PwSrv->Connect(_T(""));
```

Dumpbin Export of the function :

```
25BE6 ?Connect@PwServer@@QAE_NPBGKPAK@Z 25BE6 __imp_?Connect@PwServer@@QAE_NPBGKPAK@Z
```

Is there something else which needs to be dine in case of linking a MFC DLL with a regular one, like adding AFX_EXT_ or something?

Kindly advise in this.
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Seems all that was required was to toggle the flag set in Project Properties>>C/C++>>Language>>Treat wchar_t as a built in type to NO. I'd never bothered with the flag before, so didn't know. The Linker error was there...

OK. Now I've another problem. The toggling of wchar_t solved the problem of the DLL linking with another MFC DLL, but now my application cannot find the entry point in my DLL. In dependency walker, it shows a mismatch between CString which the application is sending, and the Unsigned Short..which my DLL is accepting ( as a result of the`wchar_t` turned off, presumably )

Comment: Check the actual name of the exported function with dumpbin. It's the same C++ decoration and calling style? When your DLL can't link with the export library of your other DLL the MFC shouldn't be in the game.

Comment: Is the function *declaration* that you're using for accessing this DLL in agreement with the name and calling convention? In C++, for example, API names are typically `extern "C"` to avoid name-mangling dependencies. Posting the *exact* linker error message content from your build-log and a dumpbin /exports of your DLL in your question would assist *greatly*.

Comment: Kindly check the Edit portion in the question above. Thanks.

Comment: Has one project been build as UNICODE and the other as non-UNICODE?

Comment: Do you maintain the callee dll project code as well? If so add that project to Project settings >> Common Properties >> Add New Reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you correctly included the .lib file for the DLL (most of the time this is down to differences in the compiler settings. e.g. UNICODE setting).

1. Check that the .lib is actually being loaded by setting the 'Show Progress' Linker settings to VERBOSE.
2. Run DUMPBIN on the LIB file to check that the exported functions are the same as the ones the linker is trying to import.

ie

```
dumpbin /ALL mylib.lib > exports.txt
```

If the name decoration is slightly different that'll give you a clue as to the problem.

Comment: This is the dumpbin export of the function which I'm trying to refer to :  `25BE6 ?Connect@PwServer@@QAE_NPBGKPAK@Z
    25BE6 __imp_?Connect@PwServer@@QAE_NPBGKPAK@Z` . And the error is as given above in the main question **Edit** portion. And the library gets loaded.

Comment: Yep, they're slightly different ('QAE_NPBGKPAK' not 'QAE_NPB_WKPAK') Were they both compiled with the same version of Visual Studio? Possible namespace issues?

Comment: Seems that wasn't the problem. All that was required was to toggle the flag set in Properties>>C/C++>>Language>>Treat wchat_t as built in Type to NO. Interesting. I'd not come across this flag before.

Comment: OK. Now I've another problem. The toggling of `wchar_t` solved the problem of the DLL linking with another `MFC DLL`, but now my application cannot find the entry point in my DLL. In dependency walker, it shows a mismatch between `CString` which the application is sending, and the Unsigned Short..which my DLL is accepting ( as a result of the` wchar_t` turned off, presumably ).

Comment: Each setting will effect the name decoration. Once those settings match the decoration will be the same and you're good to go.

Comment: But what should I be looking at? The wchar_t switch OFF is essential to my MFC DLL connecting with the 3rd party DLL. But this switch causes problems with the Application using the MFC DLL.

Comment: Is the method accepting a LPCTSTR? You might need to manually cast, e.g. (LPCTSTR)strMyCString.

Comment: When I put the app in dependency walker, this is what my DLL is exporting : `int CTestDLLApp::PrintMessage(class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > >)`.  And this is what my application is trying to access : `int CTestDLLApp::PrintMessage(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >)` . You can notice the unsigned short instead of whar_t, because of the switch turned off.

Comment: You could simply create your own ATL::CStringT< USHORT, StrTraitMFC_DLL< USHORT > > as a 'bridge' to the other dll.